# Cascade dxDropDown with dxTreeView inside dxForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I am created cascade dxDropDown with dxTreeView inside dxForm which is working very nice, but in child dxDropDown selected item is not showing in dxDropDown textbox.

I found the issue as I have onOpened event dataSource filter. Once I remove onOpened it start working but my child dxDropdown will stop filtering.

```
onOpened(e: any) {
            tvDepartment.option(
              "dataSource",
              getDistinctDepartments(
                UploadForm.getEditor("Division")?.option("value")
              )
            );
          },
```

I have simulated whole over here https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kate-2cm25p?file=/src/index.ts:2789-3016.